# how to fix this error show in preview layer geoserver?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, geoserver

i use mysql(phpmyadmin)like a database and geoserver to publish my layers, when i have the big layers they show me in preveiw layer this error, what is the problem with the big layers and connection mysql_geoserver and  how to fix this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is not caused by the database simply crashing, then there are a number of setting in the store that you can use to help maintain connections to a remote database.

You may need some or all of them to overcome this issue. First I would turn up the connection timeout (in seconds), then I would look at
increasing the max connections as you may be running out of them. If none of these help you will need to examine the GeoServer logs (at GeoTools Debug level) to find the actual query being sent to the database and then use the database tools to see if you can speed up that query (may be add an index).

[image]